# Nuxt Set src URL for application without effecting routing

Tags: configuration, nuxt.js

I'm trying to set a base URL to the src URLs for my application to be '/static/' without affecting the routing or folder structure

Tried setting the router to '/static' but that changes the routing. Also tried to set the publicPath to '/static/_nuxt' but that generates a new folder so the structure ends up being '/static/static/_nuxt'.

```
//this changes the routing

module.exports = {
  mode: "spa",
  generate: {
    dir: "dist/static"
  },
  router: {
    base: '/static/'
  }
}`

//this changes the file path:

module.exports = {
  mode: "spa",
  generate: {
    dir: "dist/static"
  },

  build: {
    publicPath: '/static/_nuxt'
  }
}
```

Haven't found a configuration option that sets the src links without affecting the routing or folder structure.

Comment: not clear what u want. What do u mean by base url but not affecting routing?

Comment: So I would like the references to include the folder as a base(src=' /static/filename') but not the routing (domain.com/) as base

Comment: If you mean links to resources like js than it's publicPath

Comment: Right, yeah I guess my question is how do I set the publicPath without generating the path? When I set it in the build it creates a new folder.

Comment: It dont create anythingl. It just affect where from your files will be served. There can be url for example. Build affects by https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-builddir/

Comment: hmm, when I set the publicPath as described in my question it generates a structure of dist/static/static/_nuxt

Comment: you are setting generate dir that do that.

Comment: So if I want the build structure to be 'dist/static/' but the links to the resources to be '/static/_nuxt' is there a way I can do that? So in effect you would have '/dist/static/_nuxt/' with resource links to '/static/_nuxt'

Comment: Your second configuration in question do exactly what u are asking

Comment: The second configuration generates 'dist/static/static/_nuxt' with the resource links to 'static/_nuxt'